# The position of my div keeps on changing based on the length of the information inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a sidebar inside a div and whenever I increase the length of the information inside the div, the sidebar changes positions. Would there be any way for me to fix the sidebar in place regardless of the information?

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this one., I have done it through flex layout. The sidebar does not change position based upon the content of main div.

```css
#main{
 background-color:#BED3E5;
overfolow:auto;
display:flex;
}
#sidebar{
background-color:#efdfbb;
flex-basis:15%;
flex-grow:0;
height:calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
asdasdasd

</div>
```